# Docker Run Image Error no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-command

i try to run a docker image with this command:

```
docker run 7ce2964461cc
```

but get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2900f69b23f22f96e520a3c8ec8681cb092c2e52bdfbb5e261ad130de1502df4-init/merged: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: Try checking [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-error-creating-overlay-mount-to-var-lib-docker-overlay2-merged-no-such-file-or-directory-error-failed-to-start-containers-mydocker/123365) out.

Answer (score 0):

try `docker inspect 7ce2964461cc`

1 to see the port to need to map **-p port_inside=port_outside**
2 the env varaible ou need to set **-e KEY=VALUE**
3 perhars mount a file inside docker **-v XX:YY**